# Problem to find the Thévenin resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I need to find the Thévenin resistance and FEM of this circuit:

[image]

I am a little confused why my answer is wrong. I mean, we could just calculate the resistance equivalent and go on with the calculations, but i really want t know where is the error in my attempt here:

First, i calculated the current through the circuit. Of course nothing flows on the resistance 7 Ohms, so the circuit is just the above part. Using basic equation: $80-6I-20-6I => 60 = 12I => I = 5 A$, so that the EFM would be $\epsilon = -20-6*5 = -50 V$.

Now we need to calculate the current of the short circuit, where the resistor next to 20V is zero. $80-20-6I_{sc}=0 => I_{sc}= 10 A$. So technically, the equivalent resistance would be $\epsilon=RI_{sc} => R = 5 Ohms$. But this is wrong... Why?

Comment: In the first sentence, I see "FEM". In a later sentence, I see "EFM". What are these? Are they supposed to be "EMF"?

Comment: By inspection, the Thevenin resistance is *at least* 7 ohms. Do you see this?

Answer (score 1):

The rule for finding the equivalent Thévenin resistance is this: replace all emf sources by short circuits and all current sources by open circuits. Then calculate the equivalent resistance between A and B. What you are doing is not this.